# IndexPath.row of CollectionView gets changed while scrolling

Tags: swift, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new in swift, the issue I am facing is I have a collection view of height 2000. when I scroll down to the bottom, the indexPath.row gets changed due to which the logic gets disturbed. I understood that this happens due to the reusability of cells but how should I stop this. This is how I am initializing cellForItemAt.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "analysis", for: indexPath) as? analysisCollectionViewCell

  if goalData.notesArr.count == 0 {
        cell?.viewNotes.isHidden = true
        cell?.constraintHeightNotesView.constant = 0
        self.constraintHeightMainView.constant = self.constraintHeightMainView.constant - 400

    }else{
        cell?.viewNotes.isHidden = false
        cell?.constraintHeightNotesView.constant = 470
    }
```

I am changing the height of a few components(cell?.constraintHeightNotesView.constant) as well as of my mainView also(self.constraintHeightMainView.constant).

Comment: Consider that `cellFortItemAt` is called once for each (visible) row and passes the current indexPath as parameter. Don't stop it.

Comment: can you please explain me in detail.

Comment: Please read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource or a tutorial about UITableView/UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

Please, edit the question so that We can see your code in full

This cell initializing method is correct

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "analysis", for: indexPath) as? analysisCollectionViewCell
```

But I can't understand why you need an collection view height 2000?

If you want to setup layout the collection view in full screen, You need to set constraints of collection view to the edges of the main view of your ViewController

if you collection view have a many elements, you will be able to scroll it.
This functionality is available without additional configuration.